# Algolia vs Elasticsearch in ecommerce

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, elasticsearch, algolia

I am adding react to a rails ecommerce website and also changing the search engine from sphynx to algolia. For this I am using react-instantsearch but I'm having a hard time integrating algolia's widgets mainly because the documentation is very unclear and I'm not sure how things are working behind the scenes. I was wondering if it would be better to use elasticsearch instead, as everything is more customisable, but I worry that the user experience will not be so spectacular.

Which one do you think is best in this situation?

Comment: What exactly is unclear to you (one of the authors of React InstantSearch here)

Answer (score 7):

Disclaimer: I'm an elastic employee

You should give a try to the site search offer that elastic provides. See https://www.elastic.co/solutions/site-search

It's a great way to get Site Search as a service without having to worry about the internals.

If you prefer to have more control but don't want to manage the cluster by yourself, have a look at https://cloud.elastic.co.

If you want to do all that manually or go to the open source only way, you can run an instance somewhere in the cloud and install elasticsearch manually.

I can't say about Algolia as I never used their service.

Answer (score 6):

Disclaimer: I'm an Algolia employee.

You can achieve a very high degree of customization with Algolia and React InstantSearch. If you are having trouble customizing the widgets (which are designed to be drop-in) you can try [Connectors](https://community.algolia.com/react-instantsearch/connectors/) instead:

> Connectors are higher order components. They encapsulate the logic for a specific search concept and they provide a way to interact with the instantsearch context.

Internally, the widgets are just pre-packaged implementations of Connectors. If there is a particular widget/connector you are having an issue with, add a comment and I'm happy to look into it!